# Why is getting three personal fouls in the first half of an NCAA basketball game a big deal

Tags: basketball, collegiate

I know five personal fouls calls for an ejection, but I cannot find anywhere why three fouls before halftime is a big deal.

Thank you for help

Comment: Who says three fouls before half-time *is* a big deal? I feel like we're missing some context here.

Comment: It comes down to math, I believe. By reaching three personal fouls before halftime, you are already 60% of the way to the limit. This suggests you will not be able to play as aggressively in the second half of the game or else be at risk of ejection.

Answer (score 1):

"Big Deal" here is subjective. There is no rule in the rule book that says "If a player accumulates three fouls before halftime, panic"

From the coach's perspective, he would be at least slightly concerned should this situation arise (his player is 3/5 of the way to fouling out, with over 1/2 the game to play); how concerned would be dependent on his strategy, his plans to adjust his strategy for the second half, how effective that player has been during the game so far, and dozens of other non-measurable reasons